# Failed to load ad (Error 1)

Tags: android, ads

Have been searching for hours on google, but still without success.
I always get the Error Message and the adBanner doesnt load:

```
There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
Failed to load ad: 1
```

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
```

Android Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
        />
```

layout

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    ads:adUnitId="pub-*****************"
    android:layout_below="@+id/middle"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

activity (imports)

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

activity

```
AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

permissions are also added

ty for your help in advance

Comment: Double check your add unit ID: I think it should look like `ca-app-pub-...`.

Comment: yeah i have also tried this one ca-app -pub...., but didnt work neither :/

Comment: Just checking if you have initialised the Google Mobile Ads SDK as follows:


`MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.admobs_app_id));
`

Answer (score 10):

I got this error on Adaptive banner for android

> **I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 1**

because of this line

```
width = (int)( metrics.widthPixels);
```

**Solution**

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

width = (int)( metrics.widthPixels/metrics.density);

AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(mContext, width);
```

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed the width passed should be the width in pixels, but it's not. It's `widthPixels / density`.

Answer (score 9):

Error 1 means the ID is wrong.

Admob gives you a number like this and is the general ID, with ~ :

```
ca-app-pub-9611919736642270~3440171884
```

And the ads id with / is to the request;

```
ca-app-pub-9611919736642270/3440171834
```

Comment: can you explain clearly? I have adUnitId with ~ I can not load add in both debug and release build. How do I fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The error code 1 refers to Invalid request.

//(public static final int ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST
The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.
Constant Value: 1) //

Thus you must check whether your Ad-Ids are defined at right place. Don't put banner ads id to interestial ads and vice versa. for other error codes just take a look on this link:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

Answer (score 0):

Add the following meta data to AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```